# Fortify issues with ASP Precompilation

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, oracle12c, fortify

I have a project that we just moved over to Oracle 12c.  Upon migration to Oracle 12c we changed the "Target CPU" to `x64` to avoid version conflict on the Oracle `dll`. Now when we run the Fortify scan against the new `x64` I get this error:

> No way to resolve conflict between "AWSSDK, Version=2.3.55.2,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" and "AWSSDK,
>   Version=1.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX".
>   Choosing "AWSSDK, Version=2.3.55.2, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" arbitrarily.

Problem is I don't have `AWSSDK` installed as a reference to the project.  We have some third party libraries we use, but I'm assuming that the third party libraries wouldn't affect the Fortify scan with this conflict. I can build the project fine in VS2015, with no conflicting versions.  As soon and I try and run the Fortify scan though I get the above error message.

I have tried to install a `AWSSDK` reference to the project in hopes that it would resolve the issue, but didn't have any success.  I have searched the files of the project to include the code and still no references.  I have even changed the "Target CPU" back to "Any CPU" but then I get conflicts with the Oracle `dll`. I am currently using Visual Studios 2015.

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Comment: **Forify**? Unfamiliar - what is that (in your title)?

Comment: Fixed the title.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Fortify will try to resolve all included assemblies so that it can ensure it's ability to walk all code paths.  It seems like you are using a 3rd party assembly that references AWSSDK and you don't have the 64bit version handy.

Comment: @JamesNix is there any easy way to determine what 3rd Party assembly that references AWSSDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after hours of searching I found this [link](https://wiki.mobilehealth.va.gov/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26772105).  Though I tried to fix all conflicts I still couldn't find what was causing the `AWSSKD.dll` issue.  I tried debugging and still no success.  Further down in the reading of the link it states to go to \Core\config\fortify.properties to alter these two properties:

```
com.fortify.VS.SkipASPPrecompilation=true
com.fortify.VS.RequireASPPrecompilation=false
```

Once I set those properties and re-scanned I was able to get a **successful** scan.  The conflicts still showed up on the scan, but it didn't stop it from processing.